How to change the default SQL Server instance
How to change the sql server default instance which was installed before?
I have two versions of SQL Server installed SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2019.
My SQL Server 2014 is the default instance. But I want to change it to be the SQL Server 2019 without deleting the SQL Server 2014 instance because both of them has own database which works correctly.
I tried many ways, but I didn't find any working way.

Perhaps all you want to do is swap over which instance is listening to port 1433 the default port. That is possible see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver16
